# For Shield ability, does Riot Trooper gain 1 power token per figure, or just 1 total?

Tags: star-wars-imperial-assault

The wording on Riot Trooper deployment cards is literally:

> **Shield:** At the end of your activation, if you have no block power token, gain 1 block power token.

As per Card Interpretations on page 2 of the rules reference, "you" refers to a figure.

Does this mean that just after the end of each activation, each of the two Riot Trooper figures will have a block power token on it (even if both ended the activation with no block power tokens)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each figure would gain a block power token.
In addition to what the original rulebook says on page 2, page 4 of *Heart of the Empire*'s rulebook, says this about power tokens:

> Various cards and abilities in Heart of the Empire allow **figures** to gain power tokens.

So power tokens are bounded to a figure and not the player who controls it.
In this case, if you control two Riot Troopers who depleted their block power tokens, both of them would gain their own token. If controlling two Riot Troopers and just one of them lost all of its block power tokens, he would win a new one.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of each Riot Trooper figure's activation, that figure gains a block power token if it doesn't have one.